# How to configure remote debugger for spring cloud data flow Local server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using the spring cloud dataflow server to create a stream. I want to do a remote debugging on the spring cloud dataflow server.
Below is the command which I am trying but not able to connect on 5005 port.
`java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the guides that Sabby pointed for debugging applications and the SCDF/Skipper server in general. Apart from this, what I notice from your question above is you have the `debug` parameters as java `program arguments` which is **incorrect**.

What you actually need is something like this:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar
```

The `debug` parameters need to be passed before `-jar` argument.

Comment: Thanks, Gopinathan it's work, I tried with, below command
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006 -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 1):

We have a FAQ describing what property to configure to [debug the applications](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.6.0.SNAPSHOT/resources/faq/#remotedebug) deployed by SCDF.

If you want to debug SCDF itself, you may want to review the [Debug Data Flow Server](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.6.0.SNAPSHOT/installation/local/docker-customize/#debug-data-flow-server) guide from the Microsite. There's also a specific section to debug the Skipper application, as well.

Comment: Updated link to adding debugging for Docker deployment: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker-customize/#debugging